# How to remove database with AMO (Analysis Management Objects)?

Tags: ssas

Can not find a way to remove database in AMO (Analysis Management Objects). This code does not work:

```
 if (svr.Databases.Contains(databaseName))
 {      
    svr.Databases.Remove(databaseName, true);
    svr.Update();
 }
 svr.Disconnect();
```

No error appears, but database still there. Same if I use Database object instead of database name. I was unable to find much about `Databases.Remove` method online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that calling `Remove()` only removes it from the in-memory collection and doesn't reflect anything on the server.

I think what you're looking for is the [`Drop()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms138650.aspx) method. So what you would do is something like:

1. Get the `Database` object by calling a method like [`GetByName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.databasecollection.getbyname.aspx)
2. Once you have the `Database` object, call `Drop()` on it